# Scroll Up for Mobile

Tags: scrolling

I need some proposal about where I can display the scroll up button in a cellphone in a user friendly approach. Any example?

Thanks!

Comment: This forum is not about "giving the right answer" it's a bidirectional thing, so let us start by you showing us what you've got so far and explain why it doesn't work for you, from there on we can give some pointers, but in the end, you can make the final call on what will work for your application and what not ;-) the current state of the question is far too open ended.

Comment: What is a "scroll up" button?

Comment: Most mobile screens don't have a "back to top" button because scrolling is so commonplace and easy to do. What are you trying to do that makes you feel such a functionality is necessary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most people are right-handed, if this is the case, then hold your phone in the hand your most comfortable with and bring your thumb naturally to the bottom, without bending it at the last joint, you find it will fall between the left-corner and center screen. This is our expected scroll zone, where the user will be making a majority of their page scrolls.

Have you ever encountered an issue with a website where you were scrolling and it jumped to a link you didn't mean to go to? Most browsers seem to have resolved these problems. However, it doesn't make sense to put a back-to-top button in a high traffic area, even if the initial issue has been resolved.

I, for these reasons, have positioned my back-to-top button on the bottom-right portion of my website, which also seems to be standard practice. Your design may call for something more original. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

For my site, I choose the bottom right hand corner for the scroll up. If you want to take left handed people into consideration too, my putting it in the bottom center.[image]

Comment: Not sure I agree that is a good place. That bottom right corner is also the position of the "floating action button" in Material Design (https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/buttons-floating-action-button.html) , used for showcasing a "promoted action". A back to top button, is a secondary action and may cause confusion for some users.

Comment: That is a good find. So maybe in the left or center then?

Answer (score 0):

Scrolling up is intuitive. It's what the user already knows how and why to do. If you have substantial vertical content and feel the need to help the user return to top, consider the method Facebook's app uses. When the user starts Scrolling up, reveal a 'back to top' button from the top of the screen. If they start to scroll down again, let it scroll out of view.

Comment: An added point: do what Apple does in the iOS browser and make a tap on the header bar scroll to the top of the page. In fact, if this is a website, please *don't* put a scroll to top button. These buttons tend to pollute the browser history (pressing back zooms you back down to the bottom of the page), and furthermore, this is a function that most browsers already take care of.